# python remove() function not working

Tags: python, python-3.4

learning Python, and for some reason I can't get the python remove function to work. It works when I'm testing it interactively in Python in the console but not when I write a script. Please help me out! it turns the input into a list but doesn't remove the vowels.

```
print("\nVowel Removal")
print("Enter a word to have the vowel removed.")
word_input = input("> ")
word_input = list(word_input)

vowels = list('aeiou')
output = []

while True:
    try:
        word_input.remove(vowels)
    except:
        print("You must enter a word.")
        break

print(word_input)
```

Comment: "It works when I'm testing it interactively in Python in the console but not when I write a script." But how are you testing it in the Python console?

Comment: `word_input = list(word_input)

vowels = list('aeiou')

word_input.remove(vowels)`

this have no sense. what exactly you try to remove?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you have:

```
word_input = list(word_input)
```

So `word_input` is a list of strings (in particular of characters). `vowels` is:

```
vowels = list('aeiou')
```

i.e. an other list of strings.

You do:

```
word_input.remove(vowels)
```

which always fails because `vowels` is a list of strings and `word_input` only contains strings. `remove` removes **a single element**. It does *not* remove all elements contained in the argument.
See the error message:

```
In [1]: vowels = list('aeiou')

In [2]: vowels.remove(vowels)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6dd10b35de83> in <module>()
----> 1 vowels.remove(vowels)

ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Note that it says: `list.remove(x): x not in list` so the argument to `remove` should be an element of the list, not a list of elements to remove.

You have to do:

```
for vowel in vowels:
    word_input.remove(vowel)
```

to remove all vowels. Moreover `remove` only removes the *first* occurrence of the element, so you may have to repeatedly call `remove` to remove all occurrences of a vowel.

Note: to remove vowels from a string you could simply use:

```
the_string.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, vowels)))
```

as in:

```
In [1]: the_string = 'Here is some text with vowels'
   ...: vowels = 'aeiou'
   ...: 

In [2]: the_string.translate(dict.fromkeys(map(ord, vowels)))
Out[2]: 'Hr s sm txt wth vwls'
```

Or if you want to use those lists:

```
result = []
# vowels = set('aeiou') may be faster than using a list
for char in word_input:
    if char not in vowels:
        result.append(char)
```

Comment: thank you for the great answer! I will accept it as the correct answer in a couple of minutes when it lets me. Thank you!